# Finding max lines in a file while printing file name and lines separately?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

So I keep messing this up and I think where I was going wrong was that the code i'm writing needs to return only the file name and number of lines from an argument.

So using wc I need to get something to accept either 0 or 1 arguments and print out something like "The file findlines.sh has 4 lines" or if they give a ./findlines.sh Desktop/testfile they'll get the "the file testfile has 5 lines"

I have a few attempts and all of them have failed.  I can't seem to figure out how to approach it at all.

Should I echo "The file" and then toss the argument name in and then add another echo for "has  the number of lines [lines]"?

Sample input would be from terminal something like

```
>findlines.sh
Output:the file findlines.sh has 18 lines
```

Or maybe

```
>findlines.sh /home/directory/user/grocerylist
Output of 'the file grocerylist has 16 lines
```

Comment: consider editing your question to include sample inputs, required output, current output and exact error messages, and the code you have worked on. It's much easier to help with a solution when we know what the expected results are. Verbal descriptions (even the best) leave a lot of room for interpretation, and hence, back and forth questions between you and the readers. Good luck.

Comment: How do I like, approve your edit or give you credit for the suggestion.  I know that's major rep on this site and you gave me super solid advice.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I'm just happy to took my advice. In the future, the better detail you can provide, the better the answer will be. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="findfiles.sh"
if [ $# -ge 1 ]
then
    file=$1
fi

if [ -f $file ]
then
    lines=`wc -l "$file" | awk '{print $1}'`
    echo "The file $file has $lines lines"
else
    echo "File not found"
fi
```

See sch's answer for a shorter example that doesn't use awk.

Comment: This works amazingly.  So I can just make a variable and then throw code after an = sign with single quotes and it works like that every time?  I keep finding that bash is kinda quirky.

Comment: Is there anyway to add validation to this?  Like for only zero or one argument and for things that are not a file?

Comment: `if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then echo zero; elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then echo one; elif [ $# -eq 2 ]
|| [ $# -eq 3 ]; then echo "two or three"; fi`

Comment: type `help test` for more expressions

Comment: `if [ -f $file ]; then echo "$file is a file"; elif [ -d $file ]; then echo "$file is a directory"; elif [ ! -a $file ]; then echo "$file does not exist (file or dir)"; fi`

Comment: A few _shell scripting bad practice_ in there: unquoted variables, no `--` before alien argument, usage of `echo`. Note that you don't need to pull `awk` if you use the `lines=$(wc -l < "$file")` syntax. There's nothing `bash` specific in there, so you could use `sh`.

Comment: @sch Thanks. I've added quotes. I don't want to steal your entire answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/sh -
file=${1-findfiles.sh}
lines=$(wc -l < "$file") &&
  printf 'The file "%s" has %d lines\n' "$file" "$lines"
```